# Give an example of a non-Riemann integrable function $g$ which is equal to a Riemann integrable function $f$ almost everywhere in $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

So I am having problems facing this exercise to find an example of such function.

Let $f\in R([a, b])$. Can we find a function $g\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere and $g$ not Riemann integrable?

Comment: What examples of non-Riemann integrable functions do you know?

Comment: What if you take the zero function and make it equal to $1$ on the rational numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ by, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.
Then $f$ is clearly R-integrable on $[a,b]$. Now define, $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ by,
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
0\quad\text{if $x$ is irrational}\\
1\quad\text{if $x$ is rational}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $g=f$ almost everywhere but note that $g$ is not R-integrable on $[a,b]$.